# Eclipse IDE dropdown menus not showing

Tags: java, ide

I'm unsure if this is the correct place to post this question or not but as you are programmers, perhaps some of you have had this issue before.

I am currently using Ubuntu 13.04 on a Notebook, I've got an error where on every version of Eclipse (Kepler, Juno, Indigo etc) the navigation bars only show a shadow.

Here is an image to show the problem -- if it helps:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQB1p.png

Is this an error with eclipse or ubuntu?
Also how would I fix this problem?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/105031/eclipse-menu-disappeared-another-one

Comment: Might be related: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=330563